# Unexpected end of JSON input : when i want to json() the response

Tags: reactjs

backend: spring boot
and every things is working on backend
but when i try to login in react i see in dev tools Chrome in Network the login is ok and the status=200 but when i try to extract the response  and jwt i see this error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz8bP.png)

this is my code

```
async sbmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        //console.log(this.state)
        await fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
        }).then(res=>console.log(res.json()))
    }
```

Comment: The only possible error that I see is from your backend. Have you reviewed the response body in the network tab?

Comment: there is no response data avaliable . this is the response in the network but header contains status ok 200 and jwt and all headers send by the backend

Answer (score 0):

`res.json()` returns a promise. You need to include your console.log in another `.then` handler and it will work. You may also be having cors issues but you should see a message in the console if that's the case. Because localhost is generally protected from other sites making requests to it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. it still not working i make it like that .then(res=>res.json()).then(res=>console.log(res))

Comment: You're going to have to provide more details on what's going on. Is there any console output at all? Are things showing up in the network tab? @med

Comment: in Network response : this request has no response data avaliable but in the headers ther is all headers send by backend including jwt and athers headers and status ok 200